# Help me fix Error: No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options. I'm use MetaMask

Tags: solidity, metamask, react, web3js-v1.x

file web3.js

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);

export default web3;
```

file image.js

```
import web3 from './web3';

const address = '0x036e58404E30795b3E5C945bc2A4107737F119cA';

const abi = myABI

export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

file app.js (frontend):

```
import web3 from '../web3';
import image from '../image';

onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const acounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    await image.methods.addImage(this.state.idUser, this.state.hashImage).send({from: acounts[0]});
    await this.getImage();
}
```

Comment: Please `console.log(acounts)` and tell us what you see.

Comment: It's return  >>> [ ]

Comment: it doesn't mean I wrong at file web3.js ?

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: You should probably unlock your account on MetaMask.